How to justify truncating at "N" char position?
I have this text:
This is the text long This is the text long This is the text long...
This is the text long This is the text long This is the text long... This is the text long This is the text long...
This is the text long This is the text long... This is the text long This is the text long...
This is the text long This is the text long... This is the text long This is the text long... etc. etc...

I want a result like this:
This is the text long This is the text long This 
is the text long... This is the text long This i
s the text long This is the text long... This is 
the text long This is the text long... This is t
he text long This is the text long... This is th
e text long This is the text long...

I have obtain this going to char number 50 and insert
a return key press (sic!) on every line.
Is possible a Vim procedure/command or external command
to obtain the same result?
I usually use:
fmt -w 50

but this is the result (very bad)
This is the text long This is the text long
This is the text long...  This is the text
long This is the text long This is the text
long... This is the text long This is the
text long...  This is the text long This is the
text long... This is the text long This is the
text long...  This is the text long This is the
text long... This is the text long This is the
text long... etc. etc...


What does "carriage return (sic!)" mean?

@Friedrich: ASCII \x0d, control code "carriage return", '\r'. "(sic!)" is a way to express that something is definitely not a typo or error. For example when you quote something with typos while preserving the typos but making clear they are from the quote, not by you. Or, in this case, that OP indeed needs to insert a CR, not a NL / newline.

A lot of people seem to interpret meaning into what I think is an unclear statement. I'm hoping for OP to clear it up. The original wording was "return (sic!)" which was edited to become "carriage return (sic!)". The actual end-of-line character depends on the 'fileformat' option and it's very unclear why it should be overridden.

I said Return which mean "press return key", someone edit message and insert "carriage return". I have edited the qestion

To get what you want you could do:
%join
%s/\v.{49}\zs/\r/g

Where:

%join join all the lines
%s/v.{49}\zs/\r/g introduce a carriage return every 49 characters

Where:

\v turn magic on
.{49} match the 49 characters
\zs define the first position to be replace

This could also be replaced by:
%join
%s/.\{49}/&\r/g

If you want to avoid the procedure to cut words in the middle you could do:
:set textwidth=49
gggwG

Where:

set textwidth force the hard wrap at column 49
gg move to the top of the buffer
gwG reformat till the end of the buffer


works perfect thanks

Thanks for the feedback :-)

only one problem: some words became "strange" for example the test "this is correct text" sometime became "th is is correct te xt" depend where is trunked. A better rule can be "truncate only if there is a space but not a complete word"
